# How to deal with dictionary on client side?

Tags: jquery, dictionary, getjson

It seems like this should be easy, but I can't seem to figure out how to access my key/value pairs:

On the server side:

```
  public JsonResult GetDict(int type)
  {
     Repository repo = new Repository();
     Dictionary<int,string> dict = repo.getDict(type);
     return Json(dict, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

One the client side:

```
  var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
  mySelect .empty();
  mySelect .append($('<option/>', { value: "", text: "-- pick one --" }));

  $.getJSON("/controller/GetDict/", { type: 1 }, function (dict, status) {
     // this doesn't work
     $.each(dict, function (index, entry) {
        mySelect .append($('<option/>', {
           value: entry.Key,
           text: entry.Value
        }));
     });
  });
```

<strike>How do I create my select list from the dictionary returned from my getJSON call?</strike>

It turns out my getJSON call is throwing an error:

Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

How can I return a key/value pair where the key is an int?  Do I need to create my own wrapper class?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass dict to `$.each` then `index` *is* a key and `entry` *is* a value, i.e.

```
$.each(dict, function (key, value) {
    var opt = $('<option>', { value:key, text: value });
    mySelect.append(opt);
});
```